# save jquery selector result into array

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to save a jquery selector's result into an array so I can reference each element later.

I tried this...

```
var found_slides = []; //create the array to hold selector results

found_slides = $(".slide"); //run the selector and store results

var current_slide = found_slides.length - 1; //find the last slide

found_slides[current_slide].fadeOut(2500); //fade out the last slide, reveals next one
```

Currently, it's not letting me run any JQuery functions on the array instances. What is the correct way to store and reference JQuery selector results?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $slides       = $(".slide"),
    current_slide = $slides.length - 1;

$slides.eq( current_slide ).fadeOut(2500);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on the last line, it should be:

```
$(found_slides[current_slide]).fadeOut(2500);
```